# Adventure movie about a boy collecting magic coins

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't know the year, but the main character was a boy who was collecting magic coins (at least, I think it was coins). The last item was in his eye.

It may be like 5-6 coins that he must find. I think either time would slow down and he would go back in time and fight for the coin or that was just the era of the movie.

There was a girl maybe a sister or friend she had powers. I think there was a villain.

Comment: +1 with your update, continue to add any details you remember

Comment: Do you remember when you watched this? VHS? DVD? Television? Movie theater? Animated (Western or Eastern)? Live-Action? Did he have companions?

Comment: Is there any chance that these are magic postage stamps and not coins?

Comment: Peanut Butter: you seem to have 3 different accounts here (the one you used to ask this question, the one you used to 'answer' it, and [the one you used to post on M&TV](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/65103/user33761)). You can follow [these instructions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts into the registered one - then you'll be able to access your question as yourself, rather than your edits having to be 'approved' by others.

Comment: This is vaguely similar to [*The Dark is Rising*](http://www.amazon.com/Dark-Rising-Sequence/dp/0689829833), by Susan Cooper, in which eleven-year-old Will Stanton inherits the task of gathering the six magical Signs that are key to the eternal war of good versus evil (the Old Ones vs. the Dark).  The Signs are circles (rings) "about the size of his palm", made of iron, bronze, wood, stone, fire, and water.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Scott Pilgrim VS The World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Pilgrim_vs._the_World)?  It's not an exact match, but there are enough similarities to make it plausible.

The main character isn't really seeking magic coins, but he gains them, video-game style, after defeating an enemy.  There is a scene near the end where he relives a battle --effectively going back in time.  The primary love interest is a girl who has the ability to move through "subspace."  There are seven "villains", with the big boss being Jason Schwartzman.

Comment: Good catch. That could match indeed.

Answer (score -1):

It's called *The Seeker: The Dark Is Rising*.

> Will Stanton's ordinary life takes a turn when he learns that he is a part of a clan of immortal warriors who have dedicated their lives to fighting the forces of the dark. — [IMDb](https://m.imdb.com/list/ls062456699/)

Release date - 5 October 2007

Comment: Was there anything to do with coins and time being funky?